# Express.js db module after refactoring routes

Tags: node.js, express, nedb

I had a simple app in node/express and after watching a course on the net, it helped me refactor the routes in my app but I found a little problem after doing so.

The problem is that my routes are using a variable called "db" that is an instance of a [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) access point.

```
var db = {
  users: new nedb({ filename: "db/users.db", autoload: true })
};
```

Of course I can  copy the 5 lines of code in the top of every route file to declare it but that would not be very DRY.

I tryed to put it in a separate file and export the variable:

```
...
module.exports = db;
```

And then import it in every file with:

```
var db = require("./db");
...
```

But this didn't worked as expected (The error was : Cannot find module './db')

This is a simplified structure of my files

```
db/
    users.db
routes/
    users.js
app.js
db.js
```

Any ideas or best practice/elegant way for solving this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to require with a relative path. If you require inside /routes folder, you must write

```
var db = require("../db");
```

Comment: I tryed that one but it threw an error because I had multiple declarations (for tests) in every file. Now that I have cleaned everything,  it works! Thank you!